# Copying corresponding values from one sheet to another based on matching value

Tags: excel, vba

I have been searching internet for a solution, but I was unable to find it. Most answers somehow reference the solution, and I think my lack of knowledge on Advanced V.Basic is preventing me to come to the solution.

I have an Excel file that has Sheet1 and Sheet2. Sheet1:ColumnA contains a list of part numbers, the Sheet2:ColumnA contains similar but more part numbers, along with Sheet2:ColumnB contains description/title of respected part number. The goal is to search "Sheet1:ColumnA.Value" in "Sheet2:ColumnA" if found, copy the description (Sheet2:ColumnB) to "Sheet1:ColumnB".

Much appreciate your help.

Comment: is vba required, or will a formula work?

Answer (score 2):

Use `VLOOKUP` in a formula (tutorial is [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php))

Comment: + 1 Yup can be easily achieved with `Vlookup()` formula